# rowcolors causes caption to be colored

Tags: tables, luatex

I have no clue why `\rowcolors` colors as well the `\caption`. The MWE doesn't make much sense by itself but should demenstrate the issue.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\aboverulesep=0pt 
\belowrulesep=0pt 
\cmidrulekern=-\tabcolsep 
\definecolor{HTML-D0}{HTML}{E03E2D}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{font=small, format=hang}
\definecolor{HTML-B2}{HTML}{3598db}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % Allow left, center and right alignment
\begin{document}

{\rowcolors{1}{HTML-B2}{HTML-B2}
\noindent
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{!{\color{HTML-D0}\vrule width 65536sp} X X}
\arrayrulecolor{HTML-D0}\midrule[65536sp]\arrayrulecolor{black}
Mugur &\Centering{} 3\\
\midrule[65536sp]
\caption{Main}\end{xltabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Running with `luatex 1.13.2.`[image]

Comment: xltabular uses longtable, and in longtable the caption is in a regular table row.

Comment: you happen to have the caption as the last row, but you can have multipe captions on any row of the table so it isn't clear how longtable could automatically catch this (well it doesn't try to at all) unrelated but don't use `\noindent` before a longtable, it won;t affect the table other than force a spurious empty paragraph before it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thx for the hint about `\noindent`. At both: How to prevent the situation? Should I simply add `\rowcolor{white}` before the caption?

Comment: `\hiderowcolors` (I think)

Comment: this hides all row colors - not that of the caption only. But one more question with this: Since caption is treated as row - page break could happen also inbetween? I thought the caption is more or less an extended attached area...

Comment: not if you put it before `\caption`  or restart with `\showrowcolors` see figure10 example of xcolor manual where some rows are white

Comment: you can use `\\*` to prevent a page break at the previous line

Comment: thx for the hint with `\\*`. For the syntax of hiding the color for just the caption I'm honestly lost. `\hiderowcolors\caption{Main}` removes all colors and `\hiderowcolors\caption{Main}\showrowcolors` raises an exception.

Comment: your caption in the document shown was at the end so why do you need to re-start colouring (you would need a `\\ ` after \caption if you do.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129942/discussion-between-leo-and-david-carlisle).

Comment: @LeO Life is easier if you try my [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package.

Comment: I need to review it. Thx for the hint. I need to verify how the combination of colored cells, borders (different color and thickness), multicolumn, extendable columns works - even with table headers and long tables with page breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\hiderowcolors` and if necessary re-start with `\showrowcolors`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\aboverulesep=0pt 
\belowrulesep=0pt 
\cmidrulekern=-\tabcolsep 
\definecolor{HTML-D0}{HTML}{E03E2D}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{font=small, format=hang}
\definecolor{HTML-B2}{HTML}{3598db}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % Allow left, center and right alignment
\begin{document}

{\rowcolors{1}{HTML-B2}{HTML-B2}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{!{\color{HTML-D0}\vrule width 65536sp} X X}
\arrayrulecolor{HTML-D0}\midrule[65536sp]\arrayrulecolor{black}
Mugur &\Centering{} 3\\
\midrule[65536sp]
\hiderowcolors\caption{Main}\\
\showrowcolors
aa&bb
\end{xltabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I treat the caption as the end of a table. Therefore I have no need to add an addtional row after it. But how to glue the caption to the table with `\\*`? Where should they be placed? Before the `midrule`?

Comment: @LeO before the midrule yes but it may be that booktabs allows a page break after \midrule in all cases, I'm not sure.